# Run ApacheBeam Pipeline on multiple runners(servers)

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I've written up a fully worked apacheBeam based pipeline, and tested it locally using direct runner. However, I want to know if it is possible to run this pipeline on multiple servers? I see that ApacheBeam typically run on GCP with auto-scale functionality. But I would like to define a set of private servers as my runner to run my pipeline.

Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated.

ps: here is the documentation of apache beam: https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.20.0/_modules/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.html

Answer (score 1):

You can run Beam pipelines in a distributed manner on an OSS runner such as [Flink](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/). See the set of runners supported in the [compatibility matrix](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah, I agree this is what I'm gonna do.